# How to display two results in a javascript string with text in the middle?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show the answer to two separate results in a popup window, however I want to have some text in between the two results. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var a;
  function setValues1()
  {
   a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
  }

  function cube()
  {
   setValues1();
   result1 = (a*a*a);
   result2 = -1*(a*a*a);
   alert("The volume of this cube is" +result1 & "and" +result2);
  }

 </script>

</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Side Length..."/>
  <input type="button" onclick="cube()" value="Calculate!"/>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix it to show the and in between the two results?

Comment: read about string concatenation in javascript.

Comment: Simple typographical miss. `+` to concatenate, not `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `&` with a `+` in your `alert` statement:

```
alert("The volume of this cube is " + result1 + " and " + result2);
```

Not sure what your intention with the `&` was, but `+` is used for string concatenation in javascript.

Comment: whitespace before and after 'and' and after 'is' would make sense

Comment: good point @gp. - editing answer now...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var a;
  function setValues1()
  {
   a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
  }

  function cube()
  {
   setValues1();
   result1 = (a*a*a);
   result2 = -1*(a*a*a);
   alert("The volume of this cube is " +result1 + " and " +result2);
  }
 
 </script>

</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Side Length..."/>
  <input type="button" onclick="cube()" value="Calculate!"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**concat()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) to concatenate strings

```
var message = "The volume of this cube is ".concat(result1," and ", result2);
alert(message);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var a;
  function setValues1()
  {
   a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
  }

  function cube()
  {
   setValues1();
   result1 = (a*a*a);
   result2 = -1*(a*a*a);
   var message = "The volume of this cube is ".concat(result1," and ", result2);
            alert(message); 
  }

 </script>

</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Side Length..."/>
  <input type="button" onclick="cube()" value="Calculate!"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation works with `+`, not `&`. Replace it with the right sign. Additionally, don't forget to add spaces within your stringified text if you intend for spaces to be there -- see the following:

`alert("The volume of this cube is " +result1 + " and " +result2);`